# c++ move semantics when using pointers

Tags: c++, move-semantics

How do I use the `move` assignment operator when working with raw pointers.

Is there any other way than doing something like:

```
void Function(T* dest)
{
    T* src = LoadT();
    (*dest) = std::move(*src);
    delete src;
}
```

Comment: `T dest = new T();` is probably wrong, did you mean `T* dest = new T();`?

Comment: Which differences do you expect between `T dest; T src; dest = std::move(src);` and `T* dest = new T; T* src = new T; *dest = std::move(*src); /* delete src; delete dest; */`?

Comment: It's very unclear what part of that way you're having an issue with.

Comment: I've clarified the real-life scenario. I want to move the newly loaded T* to the dest*
I could of course create a function called move, mut i wanted to use the built-in move assignment operator.
However, that requires references rather than pointers. I wanted to know if there is and smart way this could be used in my case.
I don't like the fact i have to use * to make the compiler understand that i want to use the move assignment operator, that's all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your move is fine. The object pointed to by src will be moved into the object pointed to by dest.

About your updated code example, the version with Function:

If your LoadT() returns a raw pointer to an object allocated with new, that does not get stored somewhere else and later deleted, you will have a memory leak.

When you std::move something, you move the *contents* of that object, the *object* itself remains alive, only "empty"/in whatever state you leave it after moving.

If you return a pointer to an object that is owned by someone else and will be cleaned up somehow beyond the code that's seen here, you could make that explicit by changing your pointers to references - that way you will explicitly specify that: a) the pointers are guaranteed to not be null; b) that there should be no worries about deleting the object you get from LoadT, since a reference can't have ownership of that object.

Comment: Is your question about std::move cleared up as well?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you reference the objects in a temporary variable you are out of luck. Technically (not sure if illegal) you are allowed to provide your own specialization of `move` in which you can hide that behavior. But at one point or another, you have to dereference those pointers.

Answer (score -1):

**You want to have** the *pointed-to-object*s moved onto one another, then you are already doing that in the correct/standard/only way, that is *de-reference* the pointer and then *move* `*src` onto `*dest`.

---

That being said, you interface is semanticly **'problematic'**. A pointer to a function is *by convention* taken to mean non-owning and optional. Ownership seems not to be the issue here, but optional is. Why use a pointer when you can use a reference ? and moreover why use a reference when you can just use return value ?

In effect you could simplify to:

```
T Function()
{
    return LoadT();
}
```

Then let users of the function decide how to best use T. If T is polymorphic you could return `std::unique_ptr<T>` instead.

Comment: Why? If I want to move the object addressed by the pointer be moved to somewhere, all is fine. swapping pointers != move of object addressed by pointer!

Comment: @Klaus which is why I said semanticly speaking - OP specificly says raw pointers and move- not moving what is pointed to..

Comment: OP didn't really specify either way

Comment: Can't catch your point! He wants to move something addressed by a pointer to another entity also addressed by a pointer. This results in having one object "moved" to the other. All is fine, the syntax and semantics is ok, especially as we always talk about a minimized example! So why you suggest a pointer swap. It is far away from the question and not at all an answer the question how move will work in context of raw pointers.

Comment: to clear things up - the destination pointer is actually a function parameter. so std::swap won'T do the trick

Comment: @HankTheTank that clears up some of the questions, i see